# jqPlot - unable to get x axis to display label correctly

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I have taken the first example directly from the jqPlot examples page:
http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php

I have put it into a jsfiddle and it's not working:
http://jsfiddle.net/vsr1kfhm/2/

Specifically the problem is with line 36. If I comment that line out the chart renders correctly but doesn't display the desired X axis labels. This is the section with the problem. The line with "ticks" on it is the problematic line.

```
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
        },
```

I'm having this exact same problem on another project. What is wrong with this, and why doesn't the example work verbatim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an extra js plugin to render the axis the way you want. Try adding this to your script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/raw/b5a7796a9ebf/src/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
```